# Examples of little Lipschitz functions

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, lipschitz-functions

Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space.

A function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called *little Lipschitz* if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y \in X$, 
$$d(x,y)<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|\leq \epsilon d(x,y).$$

Question: What are the examples of little Lipschitz functions? When $X=\mathbb{R}$, I can only think of zero function as we have 
$$\dfrac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \leq \epsilon$$
for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Take $X = [0,1]\cup \{2\}$ and $f$ to be the characteristic function of $\{2\}$. Perhaps something more dramatic can be constructed on totally disconnected spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X:=({\mathbb R},d)$ be the real numbers provided with the metric $d(x,y):=\sqrt{|x-y|}$.

(It is easily checked that $d$ is indeed a metric on ${\mathbb R}$. The reason for introducing $d$ is that $d$-distances between nearby points $x$, $y$ are "infinitely larger" than $|x-y|$.)

As a simple example consider now a function $f:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ which is $1$-Lipschitz in the usual sense:
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|\ .$$
I claim that such an $f$ is little Lipschitz on $X$.

*Proof.* Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given, and put $\delta:=\epsilon$. Then from $\sqrt{|x-y|}=d(x,y)\leq\delta$ it follows that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|=\sqrt{|x-y|}\sqrt{|x-y|}\leq\delta\sqrt{|x-y|}=\epsilon\> d(x,y)\ .$$

Comment: May I know what is the motivation behind the metric $d(x,y) = \sqrt{|x-y|}$?

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example consider now a function $f:(0,1]\to(0,1]$ which $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ then 
\begin{equation}
d(x,y)<δ⇒|f(x)−f(y)|≤ϵd(x,y).
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\forall\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, ~~\vert x-y\vert<\delta\Longrightarrow \vert \frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\vert<\epsilon
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\vert\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\vert}{\vert x-y\vert}<\epsilon
\end{equation}