# Prove that $lip_0(K)$ is separating if and only if it is weak$^*$-dense in $Lip_0(K)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Please refer here for the definition of [little Lipschitz functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548275/examples-of-little-lipschitz-functions).

The following statement is the first sentence in the proof of [Lemma $2.4$](http://adalet.perso.math.cnrs.fr/freespaceMAPcompact.pdf).

> Using Hahn-Banach Theorem, one can prove that $lip_0(K)$ is separating if and only if it is weak$^*$-dense in $Lip_0(K)$.

Question: How to prove the statement above?

Remark: Let $X$ be a Banach space. A subspace $S$ of $X^*$ is called *separating* if $x^*(x)=0$ for all $x^* \in S$ implies $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, let $X$ be a Banach space and $S\subseteq X^*$ be a linear subspace.  Then $S$ is separating iff it is weak*-dense.

First, suppose $S$ is separating and let $U\subseteq X^*$ be a nonempty open set.  Shrinking $U$, we may assume it has the following form: for some finite-dimensional subspace $Y\subseteq X$, some $g\in Y^*$, and some $\epsilon>0$, $$U=\{f\in X^*:\|f|_Y-g\|<\epsilon\}.$$

Let $T$ be the subset of $Y^*$ obtained by restricting each element of $S$ to $Y$.  Then $T$ is a separating subspace of $Y^*$.  Choose a basis $B$ for $T$ and extend it to a basis $B'$ of $Y^*$, and consider the dual basis on $Y$.  Then every element of $T$ vanishes on the dual basis elements corresponding to elements of $B'\setminus B$.  Since $T$ is separating, there can be no such elements, so $B=B'$ and $T=Y^*$.  In particular, $g\in T$.  This means there exists $f\in S$ such that $f|_Y=g$, and hence this $f$ is in $U$.  Thus $S\cap U\not=\emptyset$.

Conversely, suppose $S$ is weak*-dense and let $x\in X$.  By Hahn-Banach, there is some $f\in X^*$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$.  The set $U=\{f\in X^*:f(x)\neq 0\}$ is weak*-open, and we just saw it is nonempty.  Thus by density of $S$, $U\cap S\neq \emptyset$, i.e. there exists $f\in S$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$.  Thus $S$ is separating.

Comment: In your second paragraph, why can we assume that $U=\{ f \in X^*| \|f|_Y - g \| < \epsilon \}$? Is it because of the definition of weak$^*$-open?

Comment: That's just a slight rephrasing of the definition of the weak* topology.  A basic open neighborhood of $g$ is given by specifying finitely many points $x_1,\dots,x_n\in X$ and $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n>0$ and taking the set of $f$ such that $|f(x_i)-g(x_i)|<\epsilon_i$ for each $i$.  Now take $Y$ to be the span of the $x_i$, restrict $g$ to $Y$, and choose $\epsilon$ so that $\|f|_Y-g\|<\epsilon$ implies $|f(x_i)-g(x_i)|<\epsilon_i$ for each $i$.